# Making a form input 100% width of what's left after the label

Tags: html, css, forms

Basically I'm trying to create this:

[image]

This is what I have so far: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/rsyugt1m/2/).

Basically I have tried setting the label and inputs to `display:block;` and making the inputs have `width:100%;`. But that of course makes the inputs break to a new line. Then I tried adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the p tags and that almost gets the effect that I need, but the inputs then go outside of the container bounds.

Any idea how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would use JavaScript to do this, since CSS *can't do the math* and this is how it would look like without changing your HTML or CSS.

(**Note:** This will work even if you change the `width` of your `.container`)

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsyugt1m/7/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>*First Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Address Line 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var fWidth = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]).width.slice(0, -2);
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  var labelWidth = window.getComputedStyle(labels[i]).width.slice(0, -2);
  var inputWidth = fWidth - labelWidth;
  inputs[i].style.width = inputWidth + 'px';
}
```

#### CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So it's not possible to do what I'm asking without javascript?

Comment: I tried doing it with CSS, but couldn't do it. Maybe some CSS expert knows a trick.

Comment: I went with your method. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 6):

Here are two solutions using CSS alone

### Solution #1: Flexbox

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsyugt1m/11/)**

Set `flex:1` on the input to fill the remaining width

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px 0 0;
}
p {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>*First Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Address Line 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Solution #2: Intrinsic Sizing

Use [Intrinsic Sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#intrinsic-sizing) by setting the value for width of the label with `min-content`:

```
label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsyugt1m/9/)**

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) for Intrinsic Sizing is actually quite good - except for IE - which currently doesn't support these values yet.

(**Edit**: This particular example seems to only work on Firefox and not on chrome, I'm not sure why though.)

Comment: What is the browser support for flex?

Comment: @Corey - Browser support is pretty good - check this out: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox